# How do I get a 2FA password hint Telethon

Tags: telethon

I use [sign_in](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html?highlight=client.sign_in#telethon.client.auth.AuthMethods.sign_in) in accaunt with enabled two-factor protection.

`await client.sign_in(phone=phone, code=code, phone_code_hash=phone_code_hash)`

Call raised **SessionPasswordNeededError**. I need to retrive a password hint field, however, I did not find in the documentation which method is responsible for this? I found a suitable method in [Madelineproto](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/PHP/danog/MadelineProto/API.html#gethint-string), but not in Telethon :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v1, [`GetPasswordRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/account/get_password.html) returns the hint:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, functions, types

async with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = await client(functions.account.GetPasswordRequest())
    print(result.hint)
```